# Python, can't figure out how to save looped variable

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dictionary

Here is my code, I am attempting to use a for loop to take an input from the user in terms of A, B, C, D, or F for 10 students that will then print the total number of A's, B's, C's, D's and F's for the entire class.

```
student = 0
for student in range(0,10):
    x = (raw_input("Enter grade here: ")).lower()
    student + 1 
print "Count for A's", x.count("a")
print "Count for B's", x.count("b")
print "Count for C's", x.count("c")
print "Count for D's", x.count("d")
print "Count for F's", x.count("f")
print("Done!")
```

Currently, it only prints the final count. I understand why, I simply am not able to figure out how to put it into a dictionary or a list as I am braindead. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Save it into a list. declare `grades = []` and then: `grades.append((raw_input("Enter grade here: ")).lower())`

Comment: @alfasin Please do not post answers in comments.

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set `student = 0` as you start looping from zero and `student` takes its value from the loop. 
Try this:

```
L = []
for student in range(0,10):
    x = (raw_input("Enter grade here: ")).lower()
    L.append(x)

d = dict((x,L.count(x)) for x in set(L))
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    print "Count for {}'s : {}".format(k.capitalize(), v)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you don't need to declare a looped variable. You also don't need to increase the looped variable. Python will take care of all of that.
And for your question; you set x to a string. Not a list.
Use this code:

```
listOfGrades = [];#to clearify, declare an empty list
for student in range(10):
    listOfGrades.append(raw_input("Enter grade here: ").lower());#add to the end of the list
print .... #do your stuff here
```

Good luck!